# Removing items from an array if they exist in another array

Tags: php, arrays

Lets say I have the following two PHP arrays that contain integers:

```
$foo = array(1, 5, 9, 14, 23, 31, 45);
$bar = array(14, 31, 36);
```

I want to remove the items in `$foo` where the same value exists in `$bar`

So the result of the process would create a `$filteredFoo` array that contains:

```
1, 5, 9, 23, 45
```

Having looked through the docs on php.net there doesn't seem to be an existing function to perform this kind of action.  So is my only option to use foreach and iterate through `$foo` checking values `$bar` on each iteration?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can use [`array_diff()`](http://www.php.net/array_diff):

> Returns an array containing all the entries from array1 that are not present in any of the other arrays.

```
$filteredFoo = array_diff($foo, $bar);
```